# I need to execute subsequent requests only in each iteration

Tags: jmeter

I have 5 requests, in first iteration i need to execute first request only and in subsequent iteration i need to execute subsequent requests. Is that can be achieved using any conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can put first request under [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller) and remaining requests under [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller) with the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) as the condition:

```
${__groovy(vars.getIteration() > 1,)}
```

[image]